# Mocking and IQueryable<T>

Tags: linq

I've ran into a problem while trying to test following IRepository based on NHibernate:

```
public class NHibernateRepository<T>: Disposable, IRepository<T> 
    where T : IdentifiableObject
{
    ...

    public IQueryable<T> Query()
    {
        return NHibernateSession.Linq<T>();
    }
}
```

How on the Hell to mock returning `IQueryable<T>` out in the way that it returns given collection in exchange certain expression. I feel I have some misunderstanding of `IQueryable<T>`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `Moq` it would be:

```
mockRepository.Expect( r => r.Query() ).Returns( myEnumerable.AsQueriable() );
```

In `RhinoMocks` it would be:

```
Expect.Call( repository.Query() ).Return( myEnumerable.AsQueriable() );
```